# How To Change Image Based on different value in drop-down

Tags: angular

​Hi All:
I have a task at work where the image field changes depending on what product type the user chooses in the drop-down.

Please see attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESGnI.png)
Please tell me what topics I should google on Angular 5 on the internet to accomplish the above tasks?

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using Angular 5.

Comment: Regardless, this question is not of sufficient quality and should be closed.